# how to recall a request for recommendation letter from professor

Tags: recommendation-letter

I asked my professor to write me a recommendation letter for graduate school, but now my plan of attending graduate school has changed. instead of going to graduate school, I will try to find a job, and get more work experiences. I know that my professor has not written my letter yet, because he said he will write it after he received request emails from graduate schools. so how should I recall the request?

Comment: Why you don't contact him/her directly to ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just write what you just did?

> Dear Professor X,
>   A while ago we talked about whether you would be willing to write a letter of recommendation for me. I have given this some more thought and have decided, instead of going to graduate school, to try to find a job in industry instead in order to get more work experience. For the time being, at least, I will therefore not need your letter after all, though I appreciate your willingness to provide one. I might come back to your offer at a later time if I decide to go back to graduate school!
>   Sincerely, Y

Comment: should I include "I might come back to your offer at a later time if I decide to go back to graduate school!" ? Because he might not feel comfortable writing me letter in the future (just my assumption).

Comment: That can be addressed whenever the time comes. But you'd at least keep the option open.